# Get SSIS Package Variable value after running it from .net

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I deployed a ssis package in the catalog and I am calling it from Application C#,I managed to execute my package parameters by passing parameters to it, but I can not get the value of a variable after the execution of the package

```
string targetServerName = "MyServer";
            string folderName = "MyFolder";
            string projectName = "MyProject";
            string packageName = "Package1.dtsx";

            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=" + targetServerName +
                ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

            IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);

            Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];

            CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[folderName];

            ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects[projectName];

            PackageInfo package = project.Packages[packageName];

            Collection<ExecutionValueParameterSet> executionValueParameterSet = new Collection<ExecutionValueParameterSet>();

            executionValueParameterSet.Add(new ExecutionValueParameterSet
            { ParameterName = "MyParam", ParameterValue = "Param Value", ObjectType = 30 });
```

Comment: What documentation have you seen that makes you think you should be able to get the value of a package variable from a .net app?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have always handled this is to create an execution log/history table in my database, and store any information I want to pass back to the application in that table.

Then after the package executes, it's just a matter of selecting the latest row from the table.

Answer (score 0):

The `SSISDB.CATALOG.EVENT_MESSAGES` DMV will return the value that a variable is changed to during execution, with the `OPERATION_ID` column being the execution ID for the specific execution instance of that package.  To do this, make sure to set the `RaiseChangedEvent` property to `True` on the variable.  This can be done in the Properties window in SSDT (highlight the variable and press `F4`).  After this, the value that the variable is changed to will be in the `MESSAGE` column of this DMV.  Additionally, to see the values of a parameter during execution you can query the `SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTION_PARAMETER_VALUES` and the execution ID will be the `EXECUTION_ID` column in this DMV.

Comment: I am a beginner in c# could you please explain your answer, or give me an exemple to what i should add in my code C#.

Comment: @SalimAissaouiTlemcani It's probably a little out of this scope, but if you want to do this from C# you'd have to connect to the server where SSISDB is and execute a SQL query.  Then you'd have query SSISDB.CATALOG.EVENT_MESSAGES using the execution ID from that package execution instance.  I'm guessing you're familiar with SQL and querying SSISDB, but to do this from C# the following link with get you started with objects from the SqlClient namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8